# C - How to read input separated by commans and whitespaces

Tags: arrays, c, csv, statistics

I have a question on how to read input and assigning it to an array (or even two arrays).

I have a project where I have to:

```
Create a C console application to compile the following statistics on a list of real number pairs:
•   minimum value;
•   maximum value;
•   median value;
•   arithmetic mean;
•   mean absolute deviation – (mean, median, mode)
•   variance (of a discrete random variable);
•   standard deviation (of a finite population);
•   mode (including multi-modal lists).
•   least squares regression line
•   outliers
```

Your program must handle any length of list.  The list will be input (or piped) from the console, or read from a file.  The list is terminated with end-of-stream (^Z) or non-numeric input.

So basically, the program has to read:

```
1,2
2,23
3,45
5,34
```

or: `1,2 3,4 5,6 7,8`
and be able to calculate their statistic properties.

I know how to do the calculations and create the functions etc. My question is, how to implement the parts: "any length of the list" and "list of real number pairs". See sample below.

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lmvq.png)

What I tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int a[100];
    int b[100];
    int n = 100;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d,", &a[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which returns a the result, but only to a fixed array length and gives me a bunch of -858993460 -858993460.

For now, I just want to know how to read the input properly and assign them to one Array, so I can read the odd and even index and calculate their mean and whatever respectively...

or assign them to two different arrays (x[], y[]), x for the digit on the left of the comma, y on the right.

Comment: You ignore the return value of scanf &Co at your own risk and restriction.

Comment: "any length of the list". Common way is to have a dynamically sized data structure. For example, a linked list where new nodes are allocated and chained as required. Or an array that is allocated with a certain size and then use `realloc` to resize it if space runs out. Different approaches have different tradeoffs.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` for input?

Comment: This is my first year learning C, and that's the only way we learned to accept user input. I wanted to use it to test first. C is a very confusing language for me :\.

Comment: You need to use a while loop for adding to your array. Once it is done you should have a variable that keeps track of the size of the array. If not then you will have a lot of garbage values in the array where you didn't assign a number.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get the entire input in a single line in a character array and then loop on the array to correctly split the char array to convert it into integer array.
Below is the code you can try :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( void )
{
  char *src = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
  fgets(src, 500, stdin);
  int arr[500];
  int index = 0;
  int n;
  while ( sscanf ( src, "%d%n", &arr[index], &n ) == 1 ) {
  //while ( sscanf ( src, "%d,%n", &arr[index], &n ) == 1 ) {  ////Use this for values separated by commas
    printf("%d\n", arr[index]);
    index++;
    src += n;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a bit too complicated for me as I have not used sscanf before and don't quite understand what the 4 arguments in it really do. I kinda understand what the overall code does, but I try to run your code and it gave me a bunch of warnings.

Comment: I just updated the code to use fgets instead of gets. This will take care of the warnings.

Comment: Sorry if I am repeating what you meant I just want to make sure I understand. So what you are saying is to read the entire input as a string then Use a loop and basically assign them to an integer array. What about the commas? What if for example the user inputed a comma separated file or text

Comment: For input containing commas replace above sscanf call with sscanf ( src, "%d,%n", &arr[index], &n ). You need to cautious as you can get input in only one format either using commas or white space. Also need to make sure that input does not span more than one line.i.e does not contain new line charachter '\n'. i have updated the answer for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The last part you said is what I am trying to do and got confused, how would you get it to read in the format as specified in my question? With both commas and new line and also white space, user just need to enter a post of integer pairs separated by white space or new line characters. I guess I will need to find a way to get the new line and spaces  consumed until it reads a number...I will experiment with your code. Thanks again

Comment: Format I’m trying to get the program to read: 1,3 3,4 4,4...or 1,3 \n 4,4 \n 3,5...etc